# Function to create a data.frame according to names variables

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I'm trying to construct a function that creates a data.frame containing only `0` from two variables indicating row and column names (it also indicates the size of the data frame in the meantime)

```
> mycolnames = c('a','b','c')
> myrownames = c('e','f')
```

For this special case my data.frame should be:

```
df = data.frame(a=rep(0,2), b=rep(0,2), c=rep(0,2))
rownames(df) = myrownames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `matrix` and wrap it in `data.frame` (if you really need a `data.frame` as the output).

```
data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = length(mycolnames), 
           nrow = length(myrownames), 
           dimnames = list(myrownames, mycolnames)))
#   a b c
# e 0 0 0
# f 0 0 0
```